# Extjs 5 grid Group Sorting

Tags: sorting, extjs, grid, grouping

In my app, I have a grid with grouping enabled. When the grid comes up, the groups are sorted in Ascending (default) order. I don't want my grid group to be sorted.

The group should be arranged in a way that the data comes from the database. The data is coming in correct order from DB. But, the sorting is happening in store level.

In grid I use this,

```
features: [{
            ftype: 'grouping',
            groupHeaderTpl: '{name}',
            enableNoGroups:true,
            depthToIndent: 20
        }]
```

In Store I use this,

```
groupField: 'groupName'
```

I even tried using these configurations in my store,

```
remoteGroup:true,
remoteSort: false
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

I created this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/in5) to test the issue that your having, I noticed that it is sorted by the grouping field by default.

I came across the `groupDir` config option on the store, Grouping will always sort either `ASC` or `DESC`, it defaults to `ASC`, You could look into creating your own [grouper](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.util.Grouper) function which overrides the `sorterFn`.

Grouping and sorting will obviosuly re-arrange the order of the elements, you may need to replicate the sorting logic in the front end that you have on the server. Turning remoteSort on should help with sorting the other columns.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `remoteSort: true` in `store`. Example:

```
Ext.define('store', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
  requires: 'model',
  model: 'model',
  groupField: 'groupField',
  remoteSort: true
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the grouper.sorterFn to  Ext.emptyFn to disable the sorting

Eg:-

```
Ext.define('store', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: 'model',
    model: 'model',
    groupField: 'groupField',
    grouper: {
        sorterFn: Ext.emptyFn
    }
});
```